# Displaying an alert for x amount of hours

Tags: php, javascript

I have an alert script in PHP which alerts an app with some sort of emergency text.
Now I need to somehow add some code which will allow an admin to set the alert as a timed alert. Presently they can set the alert and then send another request which will remove the alert.

The code below has been altered to reflect what I currently am using, I have most of it working, except the removal after the time expire, aka the goto a; routine.

```
$filename = "alertCheck.php";
 $timedalertsingle = $_POST['timedalertsingle'];
 $timedalerthours = $_POST['timedalertchoice'];
 $timestamp = time(); 
 $timedalertseconds = $timedalerthours * 3600;

 // Testing the variables
 echo $timedalertsingle."<br />";
 echo $timedalerthours."<br />";
 echo $timestamp."<br />";
 echo $timedalertseconds."<br />";
 echo ($timestamp + $timedalertseconds)."<br />";

// write the file
$fp = fopen ($filename, "w"); 
if ($fp) {
    fwrite ($fp, $timedalertsingle);
    fclose ($fp);
    echo ("<span style='color: #6FF;'>File written:</span> " . " This alert will last for " .$timedalerthours . " Hour(s)" . "<br />");
    echo date('m-d-y') ."<br />";
}
else {
    echo ("File was not written");
}

// test the time
a:
if (time() > ($timestamp + $timedalertseconds)){ 

    // overwrite the file 
    fwrite ($fp);
    fclose ($fp);
    echo ("<span style='color: #6FF;'>There are no alerts.</span> ");
}
else {
    goto a;
}
```

My input (changed to reflect new variable names:

```
<form action="processtime.php" method="post" name="timedalert">
<strong>Post a Timed Alert: &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><input name="timedalertsingle" size="60" type="text" /><br />
<strong>How many hours this alert will be displayed: </strong>
<select name="timedalertchoice" />
  <option value=".0833">5 Minutes</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="1">1 hour</option>
  <option value="2">2 hours</option>
  <option value="4">4 hours</option>
  <option value="6">6 hours</option>
  <option value="8">8 hours</option>
  <option value="12">12 hours</option>
  <option value="18">18 hours</option>
  <option value="24">24 hours</option>
</select>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /><br />
</form>
```

So here is what my processtime.php page looks like after this runs:

tree fell half of building 93 is in Cuppertino
24
1354217471
86400
1354303871
File written: This alert will last for 24 Hour(s)
11-29-12

Problem is that it does not stop the alerts after the given time.
Help! TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to run the 'Alert' after a specific time period, say 2 hours for now. I guess you shall have to take a input field as Date/Time from the user asking him to specify the start time of the Alert

Then you run a Cron Script every 2-5 minutes and perform the required action

Comment: I'm not sure I can use CRON on this server and won't it be resource heavy checking every few minutes if the alert has expired? Especially if it is a 48 hour alert.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were sending mail alerts, sorry

Answer (score 0):

When the alert is saved, set an "expires" field (date/time to stop displaying it).  When the page loads if expires > now, display the alert.

You can't put PHP code inside Javascript.  PHP is executed on the server, and the client-side Javascript only sees the RESULT of the PHP code.  You can't have JS code execute PHP code except by sending a new http request to the server (page reload or ajax request).

Comment: I understand the 2nd part of what you wrote (can't have JS execute PHP) etc.. but when I save an alert and set an expires field how do I calculate when 1 hour or 8 hours has passed. Don't I need to somehow get the current time and create a timer write the alert to the alertCheck.php and then, when the timer reaches its end, write to the alertCheck.php a blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RadamsAlert {
const ALERT_FILE = 'alerts.dat';

function addAlert($alertMessage, $expirationTime){
    $alert = array('alert' => $alertMessage, 'expiration' => $expirationTime);
    $alerts = $this->readAlerts();
    $alerts[] = $alert;
    $this->writeAlerts($alerts);
}

function readAlerts(){
    $alerts = array();
    if(file_exists(self::ALERT_FILE)){
        $contents = file_get_contents(self::ALERT_FILE);
        $readAlerts = unserialize($contents);
        if(count($readAlerts) > 0){
            foreach($readAlerts as $alert){
                if($alert['expiration'] > time()){
                    $alerts[] = $alert;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $alerts;
}

function writeAlerts(array $alerts){
    file_put_contents(self::ALERT_FILE, serialize($alerts));
}

}

$timedalertsingle = isset($_POST['timedalertsingle']) ? $_POST['timedalertsingle'] : false;
$timedalertseconds = isset($_POST['timedalertchoice']) ?    (int)$_POST['timedalertchoice'] : 0;
$timestamp = time();

if($timedalertsingle !== false && $timedalertseconds > 0){
$radAlert = new RadamsAlert();
$radAlert->addAlert($timedalertsingle, $timedalertseconds + $timestamp);
}

header('Location: sec.html');
exit();
```